# Get the last inserted id using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am stuck with a problem .
i need the last inserted id from the table which is to be added to same table, i.e in my table i 've two fields "id" and "translation-of" they both should save the same value. Id field is auto increment.How to implement this???? Am also uploading the categories using excel in that case also same problem... Please help me with this....

my controller function is

```
$insert[] = ['translation_lang'=>'en','parent_id' =>$a[0],'name' => $value->name,'slug' =>$value->name,'description' => $value->description,'picture'=>$pic,'active'=>1];

$last_id =    \DB::table('categories')->max('id');  

if(!empty($insert)){                            
    \DB::table('categories')->insert($insert);
    \DB::table('categories')->where('id2',$last_id)->update(['translation_of' => $last_id]);
    return Redirect::to('admin/category');
}
```

Waiting for a response.

Comment: Storing the same information twice sounds like a waste of storage. Maybe you need to change your scenario, or give a little more insight on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using

```
\DB::table('categories')->insert($insert);
```

Use

```
\DB::table('categories')->insertGetId($insert);
```

The method [insertGetId](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts) will insert the datas and then return the incremented ID of the inserted line.

Comment: am getting an error while using " \DB::table('categories')->insertGetId($insert); "

Comment: Error ---- " ErrorException in helpers.php line 747:
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array "

Comment: That's because the insert should be only an ```array```, not an ```array``` within an ```array```. So, instead of ```$insert[] = ['tra...``` do ```$insert = ['tra...```. This is because it needs one single line inserted to return the corresponding ID.

Comment: so if i want to insert array of data ,what should i do ?? because i am uploading categories through excel so there will be lot of data to inserted at the same time.. So how to implement this?

Comment: You can foreach on the datas and use the last IDs on every iteration. Either way you can't do all this in one single SQL request, it can't see the future.

Answer (score 1):

use insertGetId in place of insert

```
$id=DB::table('categories')->insertGetId($insert);
```

`$id` is your last insert id